# Downloading a file and redirecting after filling a PHP form

Tags: php, forms, redirect, download

I wrote a PHP form that downloads a file after filling it. It works but I would like it to also redirect to a "Success" page afterward. I was able to do one or the other, but not both. I guess this is because the header function cannot be used twice. I tried moving the 'header(Location)' part around but it did not work. Is there a way to do it?

The code I used:

```
[...]

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    $file = 'example.pdf';
    if (file_exists($file)) {

        /* This part works */
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit;

        /* This part does not */
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/success');
    }
}
```

Comment: You can serve a file or issue a redirect, but not both. It's a limitation of HTTP.

Comment: "the header function cannot be used twice"...er, you've used it 8 times. And all of them worked. What the browser did with them is a different matter. Sammitch is right - you're issuing conflicting instructions to the browser, and in this case it'll deal with the download (i.e. process the response), but it cannot process the response _and_ do a redirect, because a redirect instruction actually means "ignore the response to this request, and go and look somewhere else instead". So logically it can't process the response _and_ ignore it.

Comment: So a solution would be to redirect to a page (e.g. example.com/success) which automatically downloads the pdf via javascript?